# Regular Expression in Python can't parse string contains dot

Tags: python, regex, string

I got a problem about Python Regex.

```
>>> import re
>>> print re.match('img', 'test.img')
None
>>> print re.match('test', 'test.img')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x7f3fac8a0100>
>>>
```

Any character after dot(.) won't be parsed, is there any way to solve this problem?

Comment: I tend to play around with regexes for python here: http://www.pythonregex.com/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`re.match` matches only at the beginning of the string. Use `search` instead. (See [`search()` vs. `match()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#search-vs-match))

```
>>> import re
>>> re.match('img', 'test.img')
>>> re.search('img', 'test.img')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x0000000002AB0100>
```